# How can I define the order of click sub-commands in "--help"

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface, python-click

I have code like this:

```
import click

@click.group()
def entry_point():
    pass

entry_point.add_command(lidtk.data.download_documents.main)
entry_point.add_command(lidtk.data.create_ml_dataset.main)
entry_point.add_command(lidtk.classifiers.text_cat.textcat_ngram.cli)
```

which gives the help text:

```
lidtk --help
Usage: lidtk [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  create-dataset  Create sharable dataset from downloaded...
  download        Download 1000 documents of each language.
  textcat
```

which is *over all* pretty close to what I want. But I would like to change the order to:

```
Commands:
  download        Download 1000 documents of each language.
  create-dataset  Create sharable dataset from downloaded...
  textcat
```

How can this be done using click?

Answer (score 16):

The order of the commands listed by help is set by the `list_commands()` method of the `click.Group` class.  So, one way to approach the desire to change the help listing order is to inherit for `click.Group` and override `list_commands` to give the desired order.

#### Custom Class

This class overrides the `click.Group.command()` method which is used to decorate command functions.  It adds the ability to specify a `help_priority`, which allows the sort order to be modified as desired:

```
class SpecialHelpOrder(click.Group):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.help_priorities = {}
        super(SpecialHelpOrder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_help(self, ctx):
        self.list_commands = self.list_commands_for_help
        return super(SpecialHelpOrder, self).get_help(ctx)

    def list_commands_for_help(self, ctx):
        """reorder the list of commands when listing the help"""
        commands = super(SpecialHelpOrder, self).list_commands(ctx)
        return (c[1] for c in sorted(
            (self.help_priorities.get(command, 1), command)
            for command in commands))

    def command(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Behaves the same as `click.Group.command()` except capture
        a priority for listing command names in help.
        """
        help_priority = kwargs.pop('help_priority', 1)
        help_priorities = self.help_priorities

        def decorator(f):
            cmd = super(SpecialHelpOrder, self).command(*args, **kwargs)(f)
            help_priorities[cmd.name] = help_priority
            return cmd

        return decorator
```

#### Using the Custom Class

By passing the `cls` parameter to the `click.group()` decorator, any commands added to the group via the the `group.command()` can be passed a `help_priority`.  The priorities default to 1, and lower numbers are printed first.

```
@click.group(cls=SpecialHelpOrder)
def cli():
    """My Excellent CLI"""

@cli.command(help_priority=5)
def my_command():
    ....
```

#### How does this work?

This works because click is a well designed OO framework. The `@click.group()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Group` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter. So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Group` in our own class and over ride the desired methods.

Steps here:

1. Override `Group.command()` so that decorated commands can be passed a `help_priority`.  In the over ridden decorator, capture the desired priority for later
2. Override `Group.get_help()`.  In the over ridden method, substitute `Group.list_commands` with a `list_commands` which will order the commands as desired.

#### Test Code:

```
import click

@click.group(cls=SpecialHelpOrder)
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command()
def command1():
    '''Command #1'''

@cli.command(help_priority=5)
def command2():
    '''Command #2'''

@cli.command()
def command3():
    '''Command #3'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli('--help'.split())
```

#### Test Results:

```
Usage: test.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  command1  Command #1
  command3  Command #3
  command2  Command #2
```

Comment: I guess the real question is to list subcommands in the order they appear.

Answer (score 13):

It's a nice description at the top, but we can achieve it more easily

```py
import click
import collections


from .aws import aws_group
from .db import db_group
from .front import front_group
from .celery import celery_group
from .i18n import i18n_group
from .deprecated import add_deprecated


class OrderedGroup(click.Group):
    def __init__(self, name=None, commands=None, **attrs):
        super(OrderedGroup, self).__init__(name, commands, **attrs)
        #: the registered subcommands by their exported names.
        self.commands = commands or collections.OrderedDict()

    def list_commands(self, ctx):
        return self.commands


@click.group(cls=OrderedGroup)
def entire_group():
    """Entire Group"""


entire_group.add_command(aws_group)
entire_group.add_command(db_group)
entire_group.add_command(front_group)
entire_group.add_command(celery_group)
entire_group.add_command(i18n_group)
add_deprecated(entire_group)
```

Just change `self.commands` from `Dict` to `OrderedDict`. As a result, my deprecated commands at a bottom of list.

Answer (score 4):

The [answer by Максим Стукало](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58323807/562769) helped me a lot. However, it was missing some typing info.
Given, we always do strict typing and given I can't edit the post, I figured I'd create another post, maybe it helps someone:

```py
import collections
from typing import Optional, Mapping

import click


class OrderedGroup(click.Group):
    def __init__(self, name: Optional[str] = None, commands: Optional[Mapping[str, click.Command]] = None, **kwargs):
        super(OrderedGroup, self).__init__(name, commands, **kwargs)
        #: the registered subcommands by their exported names.
        self.commands = commands or collections.OrderedDict()

    def list_commands(self, ctx: click.Context) -> Mapping[str, click.Command]:
        return self.commands
```