# Click: Customize "Missing argument" error handling by overriding UsageError's show function

Tags: python, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, python-click

I´m currently trying to customize the error handling when a command was given without providing needed arguments using Click.
According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39596070/python-click-custom-error-message) this can be done by overriding the `show` function of `click.exceptions.UsageError`. 
However, I tried to modify the provided solution there but I couldn´t get it to work.

In my case, I want to be able to get the command that should be executed (but failed due to missing arguments) and depending on the entered command, I want to process further.
My sample code looks like this:

```
@click.group(cls=MyGroup)
def myapp():
    pass

@myapp.command()
@click.argument('myarg',type=str)
def mycommand(myarg: str) -> None:
    do_stuff(myarg)
```

So if the command was something like `myapp mycommand` and it misses needed arguments I want to handle it individually.
I searched for a while, but I was not able to figure out HOW to fetch the command (I tried passing the context but as far as I read, `UsageError` gets no context passed on initialization).

I´d be grateful for any hint or ideas.

EDIT: The implemenation of `myGroup` looks like this:

```
class myGroup(click.Group):
"""
Customize help order and get_command
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47984810/713980
"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.help_priorities = {}
    super(myGroup, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def get_help(self, ctx):
    self.list_commands = self.list_commands_for_help
    return super(myGroup, self).get_help(ctx)

def list_commands_for_help(self, ctx):
    """reorder the list of commands when listing the help"""
    commands = super(myGroup, self).list_commands(ctx)
    return (c[1] for c in sorted((self.help_priorities.get(command, 1000), command) for command in commands))

def command(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Behaves the same as `click.Group.command()` except capture
    a priority for listing command names in help.
    """
    help_priority = kwargs.pop('help_priority', 1000)
    help_priorities = self.help_priorities

    def decorator(f):
        cmd = super(myGroup, self).command(*args, **kwargs)(f)
        help_priorities[cmd.name] = help_priority
        return cmd
    return decorator

def get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name):
    rv = click.Group.get_command(self, ctx, cmd_name)
    if rv is not None:
        return rv
    sim_commands = most_sim_com(cmd_name, COMMANDS)

    matches = [cmd for cmd in self.list_commands(ctx) if cmd in sim_commands]
    if not matches:
        ctx.fail(click.style('Unknown command and no similar command was found!', fg='red'))
    elif len(matches) == 1:
        click.echo(click.style(f'Unknown command! Will use best match {matches[0]}.', fg='red'))
        return click.Group.get_command(self, ctx, matches[0])
    ctx.fail(click.style(f'Unknown command. Most similar commands were {", ".join(sorted(matches))}', fg='red'))
```

Comment: Hello again. Could  you post your implementation of `MyGroup` please?

Comment: Hey ;), I edited my post above.

Comment: so, to clarify, you want to be able to have a custom error message if `myarg` isn't passed into your command invocation?

Comment: Yes, but additionally I want to be able to actually know which command has been invoked in order to do a bunch of other stuff depending on that command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a first draft and the most naive solution I can think of, so it might change it if doesn't fully solve your problem. Would changing your code to something like this help?

```py
@click.group(cls=MyGroup)
def myapp():
    pass

@myapp.command()
@click.argument('myarg',type=str, required=False)
def mycommand(myarg: str=None) -> None:
    validate_my_command(myarg) # this is where you do your custom logic and error message handling
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that it's explicit and holding in line with `Click`'s suggested way of doing this. However, if you wanted to do this for every command, we can consider more complex approaches

Let me know what you think

Comment: Cool, nice solution didn't think of setting required to `False` that's very intuitive.
I think I will go with this for my other commands as well and avoid implementing anything too complex.

Out of curiosity: What would be a more complex approach like?

Comment: I couldn't really tell you. I imagine something along the lines of either decorating a click command that does this validation for you, which sounds doable. 
Or, rolling your own implementation of a `Command`, but that's liable to change whenever the Click API changes (not that often, but something to be mindful of).

Comment: Creating my own decorator sounds quite interesting. But nevertheless thanks again ;)

Answer (score 0):

These days `click.command` has the `no_args_is_help` parameter, see [docs](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.Command). This was introduced in [version 7.1](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/changes/#version-7-1).